# python polling and start after another Popen has finished

Tags: python, subprocess

In python, I'm using polling notifications with callback so when files are detected in a bucket, then from in the python script, I run a shell script, which runs a series of python commands anywhere from 1-10 min long.

I would like that shell script to fully complete before running the shell script again, but the polling notifications attempts to as new files are detected.  I would like them to wait until complete.

```
def run_shell_script(summary_message):
    cmd = './process_job.sh' + ' ' + summary_message + ' &'
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()  
    p_status = p.wait()

def poll_notifications(project, subscription_name):
    """Polls a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription for new GCS events for display."""
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    project, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    summary_message = summarize(message)
    run_shell_script(summary_message)

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that your subprocess created child process to execute the ".sh" command. One way to remedy this is to have all the child processes wait also. For example,

```
import psutil

def run_shell_script(summary_message):
    cmd = './process_mlbox_job.sh' + ' ' + summary_message + ' &'
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True)
    parent = psutil.Process(p.pid)
    [child.wait() for child in parent.children(recursive=True)]
    (output, err) = p.communicate()  
    # wait_to_finish(p)
    p_status = p.wait()

#def wait_to_finish(p):
#    parent = psutil.Process(p.pid)
#    children = parent.children()
#    for child in children:
#        wait_to_finish(child)
#        child.wait()
#    p.wait()
```

However, this may be subjected to race conditions if the p process dies too fast.

---

If that wasn't the issue, there is another way to manage run_shell_script process and the callback process. You can track active subprocesses with a global list and only start new subprocess when that list is empty. For example,

```
messages_to_run = []
active_processes = []

def run_shell_script():
    if not messages_to_run: # indicating no messages to run
        return
    if active_processes:
        if active_processes[0].poll() is None: # indicating last process is still running
            return 
        active_process.pop(0)
    summary_message = messages_to_run.pop(0)
    cmd = './process_mlbox_job.sh' + ' ' + summary_message + ' &'
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True)
    active_processes.append(p)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()  
    p_status = p.wait()
```

Separately, you need an infinite loop that keeps calling "run_shell_script" and appending any new messages to "messages_to_run"

Comment: I tried the option 1 using psutil and get the following error: "psutil._exceptions.NoSuchProcess: psutil.NoSuchProcess no process found with pid 28873".  Thoughts?

Comment: As suspected, the subprocess probably already died when it’s psutil. You can try moving it higher up right after subprocess.Popen(). See if that works.

Comment: I tried with option 2 with the global variables and the infinite look calling "run_shell_script", however, it doesn't wait as expected, so run like it did before.  Thoughts?

Comment: This also indicates the issue that the shell process you called with Popen spawns child process to do the work. The shell process itself dies before the child process finishes the work. I would try method 1 and move wait_to_finish to right after Popen. Updated answer above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: For option 2, the active_processes[0] is 0, therefore it thinks it's complete, but it's not.   That shell script I have is still running a python script that hasn't finished.  What am I missing here to identify that?

Comment: Should I have the " &" removed?  Appears that detects "none" correctly.

Comment: Yes. "&" starts the process in the background. Removing that would detect none correctly. By removing it, even your original code may work, as p.wait() waits until the process is finished.

Comment: Got it working by removing the '&' and also making sure my infinite loop was working.